# mingw32-g++ compile to 16bit instead of 32 or 64

Tags: windows-7, architecture, compilation, g++, mingw32

I'm compiling very simple code in windows7 64bit.
(in C:\MinGw\bin) "mingw32-g++.exe -c -Wall filepath\filename.cpp -o filepath\filename.exe"
When the .exe run, it give me 16-bit incompatibility error on the system.
Adding -m32 in the compiling arguments, the result are the same;

I'm using MinGwfrom www.mingw.com actually I don't want use IDE.

What could be the solution?
p.s. This happen since I've installed and try various IDE, it is possible that some of these have installed a different version of mingw, have changed some path or have changed the configuration somewhere. I tried code::blocks, codelite, microsoft visual studio express(didn't go right).

Thanks